# MySQL Count based on text word

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

AS I am working on the count of how many SKU (based on EACH SKU), as I know the SKU 'H-ROOT-C' are 3 item has been refunded.

```
SELECT 
    sku,
    count(IF(transaction_type = 'Refund'AND amount_description = 'Principal' AND amount_type = 'ItemPrice', sku, 0)) AS 'refund_QTY_Order'
FROM
    settlements_qty_test
WHERE
    (sku NOT LIKE '%loc%'
        AND sku NOT LIKE 'isc%'
        AND sku NOT LIKE 'trek%')
GROUP BY SKU ='H-ROOT-C'
HAVING sku IS NOT NULL AND LENGTH(sku) > 0
ORDER BY refund_QTY_Order ASC
```

Result output

```
'H-ROOT-C', '125'
```

I keep get results as 125 counts on all refunds as I want this search focus on each group of SKU and h-root-C should be 3 item return, not 125 item return. I don't want all SKU refund, I want this SKU='H-root-c' only.

Comment: `GROUP BY SKU ='H-ROOT-C'` ... does this query actually run on MySQL?

Comment: It was working fine for another function on MySQL in my side, Any suggestions what should I use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify this to:

```
SELECT sku
       sum( (transaction_type = 'Refund' AND
             amount_description = 'Principal' AND
             amount_type = 'ItemPrice'
            )
           ) AS refund_QTY_Order
FROM settlements_qty_test
WHERE sku NOT LIKE '%loc%' AND
      sku NOT LIKE 'isc%' AND
      sku NOT LIKE 'trek%' AND
      LENGTH(sku) > 0
GROUP BY SKU
ORDER BY refund_QTY_Order ASC;
```

The comparison to `NULL` is redundant.  I left the conditional logic in the `SELECT` so you will get `0` values.

Comment: That is Prefect, that's what I am looking for. Seems my code was in misplace and seems IF is an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    SELECT 
    sku,
    count(sku) AS 'refund_QTY_Order'
FROM
    settlements_qty_test
WHERE (sku NOT LIKE '%loc%' AND sku NOT LIKE 'isc%' 
AND sku NOT LIKE 'trek%' 
AND sku IS NOT NULL AND LENGTH(sku) > 0 
AND transaction_type = 'Refund'AND amount_description = 'Principal' 
AND amount_type = 'ItemPrice')
GROUP BY SKU ORDER BY refund_QTY_Order ASC
```

> If you want records that has sku 'H-ROOT-C' only then:

```
    SELECT 
        sku,
        count(sku) AS 'refund_QTY_Order'
    FROM
        settlements_qty_test
    WHERE (sku IS NOT NULL AND sku='H-ROOT-C' 
    AND transaction_type = 'Refund'AND amount_description = 'Principal' 
    AND amount_type = 'ItemPrice')
    GROUP BY SKU ORDER BY refund_QTY_Order ASC
```

Comment: That is Prefect, that's what i am looking for. Seems my code was in misplace and 'IF' should be remove